# create-elm-app: How can I run elm-app start through a reverse proxy

Tags: elm

I am new to create-elm-app.

I need to run `elm-app start` via a reverse proxy which routes http://myhost/myprefix to http://localhost:3000.

However this would require that links (e.g. to css and js) refer to /myprefix/*

For elm-app **build** this can be achieved with 
`PUBLIC_URL=myprefix elm-app build`

However for **start** `PUBLIC_URL=myprefix elm-app start` this does not work, i.e. links refer to / instead to /myprefix

Any help would be appreciated